# css dropdown menu link are always outside the menu ..not toggling when button is clicked

Tags: html, css

hi the dropdown content isalways shown.. but i want it only when dropbutton is clicked ..on clicking the button background toggles in and out but the links remain outside the menu permanentaly.. please see

i have also attached screenshot below ..to be more clear
navbar css

```
.header-nav {
background-color: rgba(0, , 6, 0.3);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
left: 0;
height: 80px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
 }
 .header-nav.bg-color {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
    .header-nav.menu-bg {
    height: 56px;
 }

           /* menu */
         .navbar-brand {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 36px;
                      font-weight: bold;
               line-height: 80px;
              padding: 0;
             text-transform: capitalize;
              }
           .header-nav.menu-bg  .navbar-brand {
                            line-height: 56px;
                         }
           .navbar-brand:hover {
                     color: #fff;
               }
                .navbar-brand > img {
                     height: 80px;
                   -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                    -moz-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                -o-transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
                transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
               }
         .menu-bg .navbar-brand > img {
              height: 56px;
          }
       .bg-color .main-menu .navbar-nav li a {
               color: #000;
       }
         .main-menu .navbar-nav li a {
          color: #22a265;
          font-size: 16px;
          padding: 30px 20px;
         text-transform: uppercase;
       -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
           -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
         transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
           }
      .menu-bg .main-menu .navbar-nav li a {
            padding: 18px 15px;
           color: #222;
         }
     .menu-bg .main-menu .navbar-nav li a:hover {
           color: #fafafa;
           }
       .main-menu .navbar-nav li a:focus {
         background-color: transparent;
         }
      .main-menu .navbar-nav li a:hover, .main-menu .navbar-nav li a.active {
                color: #fff;
             background-color: #04b962;
         }
     .menu-bg {
           background-color: #fff;
         box-shadow: 0 2px 10px -1px rgba(87, 97, 100, 0.35);
         }
      a img.logo-color  {
           opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
          }
     .menu-bg a img.logo-white  {
         opacity: 0;
        height: 0;
           }
          .menu-bg a img.logo-color  {
                opacity: 1;
           }

           .main-menu .navbar-nav li a.menubgactive {
          background-color: #f0f0f0;
              }
           .main-menu .navbar-nav li a.menubgactive:hover {
           background-color: #04b962;
           }

      /* navbar-toggle responsive menu */
         .navbar-toggle {
            border: none;
        background: transparent;
         }
       .navbar-toggle.collapsed .icon-bar {
             background-color: #04b962;
       }
      .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
               background-color: #e91313;
        }
     .navbar-toggle:hover {
                background: transparent;
        }
         .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
                width: 32px;
                height: 4px;
           -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
           -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
           -ms-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
           -o-transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
            transition:all 0.2s ease 0s;
          }
      .navbar-toggle .top-bar {
           -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
         -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
          -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
          -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
            transform:rotate(45deg);
            transform-origin: 10% 10%;
         }
          .navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
                opacity: 0;
         }
          .navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
                -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
               -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
               -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
               -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
              transform:rotate(-45deg);
                transform-origin: 10% 90%;
                     }
         .navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
                -moz-transform:rotate(0);
               -webkit-transform:rotate(0);
               -o-transform:rotate(0);
                -ms-transform:rotate(0);
                transform:rotate(0);
                 }
           .navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
                        opacity: 1;
         }
            .navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
               -moz-transform:rotate(0);
               -webkit-transform:rotate(0);
                    -o-transform:rotate(0);
                -ms-transform:rotate(0);
                 transform:rotate(0);
                }


                 .dropdown {
                    position: relative;
                     display: inline-block;
                     }

               .dropdown-content {
                     display: none;
                      position: absolute;
                          background-color: #f1f1f1;
                     min-width: 160px;
                   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                   z-index: 1;
                   }

           .dropdown-content a {
                         color: black;
                         padding: 12px 16px;
                         text-decoration: none;
                         display: block;
                       }

              .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

             .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

             .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

i want to click on 'stock' to open further links but they are always open

menu html..

```
                             <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-333" data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Stock
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-default" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">   </div>
      <a class="dropdown-content " href="#">Pick list</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Satt i lager</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Telling</a>

  </li>
```

[image: problem image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use css to do this, you would do something like this:

You would include:

```
display: none;
```

And in include:

```
element:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using bootstrap css, then you can do this way**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pulse.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary h-100 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Primary</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a  href="">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="">Shop</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="">Products</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Secondary</li>

                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```